# SAMBA - share not reachable without group permission

Tags: samba

**In short:** if directory has 700 permission on linux machine being owner I'm not allowed to open the directory from windows. If I change it to 750 or 770 it works.
The same happens for files (but with 600 vs 640/660) .

**The longer description:**
I'm reinstalling our server under CentOS7. We were using samba for a simple sharing of directories.
SELinux is off and the firewall allows connections.

```
more /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)

uname -r
3.10.0-862.2.3.el7.x86_64

sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled

firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all |grep samba
        rule family="ipv4" source address="XXX.YYY.ZZ.1/24" service name="samba" log prefix="samba" accept

rpm -qa |grep samba-4
samba-4.7.1-6.el7.x86_64
```

The `testuser` belongs to `testgroup`

```
id
uid=1001(testuser) gid=1000(testgroup) groups=1000(testgroup),100(users)
```

Samba's config-file (some of options like write_list should not be required; valid_users should be enough - I was desperate):

```
[global]
# ...usual staff like master, group, netbios-name...
        load printers = no
        printing = cups
        veto files = /*.[mM][pP]3

        interfaces = lo enp3s0f0
        security = user
[TestUser]
        path = /home/testuser
        writeable = yes
        browseable = yes
        read only = no
        valid users = testuser
        write list = testuser
        read list = testuser
        printable = no
        create mask = 0640
        directory mask = 710
        force create mode = 0640
        force directory mode = 0710
        inherit acls = no
        inherit permissions = no
```

I tested all files/directories in question with `getfacl /home/testuser/SOME/PATH` and all they have either 600/700 or 660/770 permissions.

**Now the problem:**
After giving of IP address of the server on windows-machine, I'm asked about user/passwd pair and then I see from windows machine all shares available on the linux server -- so far so good. Samba log indicate that `testuser` has successfully connected to service `TestUser`. I select my own share and then...

...if group has no read permission on the file (or rx for directories) I am not allowed to open file/dir from windows but I can do whatever I want on linux machine after log-in with `ssh`. If I change permission to 644/750 then I can also work on these files from windows.

If samba is force to write files/dirs with 600/700 then the empty file/dir is created and immediately windows application tells me that I have no rights to work on it.

I tested a lot of different settings of file and and directory masks, creation, etc in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and I can't get it running.

I'm out of ideas how to solve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change the ownership of folder. Also test with basic config like following. I hope this might work.

```
[TestUser]
        path = /home/testuser
        browsable =yes
        writable = yes
        guest ok = yes

chown -R testuser:testgroup /home/testuser/
chmod -R 700 /home/testuser/
```